# XCode 15 command+click menu in source code?

Tags: xcode, xcode15

There was a Cmd+Click menu in text editor in XCode 14 with quick actions in it
But in XCode 15 Cmd+Click jumps to definition instead. Is there a way to restore that menu back?

I'm well aware people didn't liked it because it originally replaced "jumps to definition", but I got liking of it for quick actions

[image: Cmd+click menu in XCode 14]

Not sure is this a question for StackOverflow and or SuperUser, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Xcode 15 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15-release-notes):

> The Show Code Actions command has been replaced with Show Quick
> Actions to quickly access any menu command. By default,
> Command-clicking a token in the editor now performs Jump to
> Definition. This can be changed in the Navigation preferences.
> Control-clicking a token brings up the standard contextual menu that
> now contains all the commands that were available in the Code Actions.

Seems like Apple removed this feature from Xcode 15. Luckily, there are 2 alternatives:

1. Right-click / control-click opens up a context menu that contains all of the options that used to be available in the "Show Code Actions" menu, plus additional actions, minus the beautiful UI.
2. A new feature called "Quick Actions" is now available when pressing ⌘+⇧+A (command+shift+A). This opens up a command palette that lets you access all of Xcode's menu options without using a mouse.

Comment: Right, so the Quick Actions palette is the same as the control-click context menu but, as you say, it can be mouseless.